# convert timestamp to Datetime in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have timestamp and want to convert it to DateTime. How can I do this in JS?
i.e.
Timestamp -

> 59080993

Want result as -

> 2016-05-30T12:10:30.407+05:30

Comment: using moment.js, you can convert timesetamp to any given format, var time = moment(1382086394000).format("DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss");

will print 18-10-2013 11:53:14;

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript)

Comment: alert(new Date(1291656749000)).toUTCString()

Comment: Also see [*How to format a JavaScript date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?s=1|6.0660).

Answer (score 4):

new Date(timestamp).toISOString()

Comment: Code–only answers are not helpful. *toISOString* is always UTC/GMT, the OP seems to want some other time zone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your timestamp is wrong. Because:

```
`new Date(59080993) //=> Thu Jan 01 1970 18:24:40 GMT+0200`
```

Comment: Yes but it is only for sample reference