# Converting Date to JS Date Object

Tags: javascript, date

I have a date in a weird format and I am not sure how to turn it into a JS Date Object. I am sure libraries like moment.js have utilities for this but I don't really want to load an entire library just for this conversion. Here is the data:

> /Date(1472586116588-0400)/

EDIT:
I have updated the back end code to use a string in the JSON instead of a C# Date time and then I convert the DateTime as follows:

```
Date.ToString("s");
```

This is giving me this string: 2016-09-02T10:13:12

So now my problem is if I do var date = new Date("2016-09-02T10:13:12"); javascript gives back:

Fri Sep 02 2016 06:13:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)

But it should give me:

Fri Sep 02 2016 10:13:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)

It appears the time zone conversion is being like doubled or something? Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: MDN Docs [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Is that supposed to be Unix timestamp?

Comment: var dateObject=new Date(1472586116588-0400); is this you want?

Comment: It would help if you describe what format that data is actually in.

Comment: A better fix here would be to go to the source of your string (this looks like a typical JSON serialised output from .NET for example), and update it to emit a date in the [format as per the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format), so it is [easily parseable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) in any browser.

Comment: Its TIMESTAMP ??? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript

Comment: Updated with new changes. Decided to go route recommended by James Thorpe

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is milliseconds since the epoch, with an `hhmm` offset, so I would do:

```js
var input = "/Date(1472586116588-0400)/";
var [match, msec, offset] = input.match(/\((\d+)([+-]\d+)\)/);
var offsetHours = Math.floor(offset / 100);
var offsetMinutes = offset - offsetHours * 100;
var date = new Date(msec - offsetHours * 60 * 60 * 1000 - offsetMinutes * 60 * 1000);

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing backend data to string in ISO 8601 formate instead of C# DateTime as follows:

date.ToString("o");

This can then simply be turned into a javascript date using new Date({string here});

Credit to James Thorpe for suggesting fixing JSON data on backend rather than hacking it to fit on the front end.