# binary format to datetime change in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

Convert a date format to normal date format like:
12-07-2017

My output is coming like:

```
/Date(1508896907290)
```

I am using angular js.

```
 {{list.DateStamp}}
```

any solutions??

convert binary format to general format?

I have tried a lot but not working.

```
      @*{{list.DateStamp | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}*@

 @*<span class="">{list.DateStamp | date}}</span>*@
```

Comment: What you refer to as "binary format" is actually called "Unix timestamp"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Can you please add little bit more code. If list.DateStamp prints a unix timestamp {{list.DateStamp | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}} should actually work. What s the output you see when you print {{list.DateStamp}}? Can you also check if you have any console errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function to convert timestamp to human date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript)

Comment: DateStamp  is in datetime format

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom filter like in below example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mydate = 1509046061730;
})
.filter('datfilter', function($filter) {
  return function(date, format) {
    return $filter('date')(new Date(date), format)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Orginal date: {{mydate}}</h1>
  <h1>Filtered date: {{mydate|datfilter:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: put this script in your app.js filter `app.filter('datfilter',....)`, an use only in expression like this `{{mydate|datfilter:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}`

Comment: Here are all date format :https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: {{list.DateStamp|datfilter:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}

Comment: waht mean you snippets ?

Comment: it comes null..returns null

Comment: what is the output of `list.DateStamp` without filter?

Comment: "/Date(1509046061730)/" this is the value

Comment: is there any way to do through moment.js??

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use moment.js with angularjs

Comment: Filtered date: null

Comment: app.filter('datfilter', function ($filter) {
        return function (date, format) {
            return $filter('date')(new Date(date), format)
        }
    })

Comment: Okay and the controller?

Comment: <div class="" ng-repeat="list in Chatmsgs">
 <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right" >
                                                   
                                                    {{list.DateStamp|datfilter:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}

                                               
                                                    </span><br>

</div>

Comment: var list = ChatService.getInfo(0, 0);
    list.then(function (d) {
        debugger
        var _results = angular.fromJson(d.data);
        $scope.Chatlist = _results;
        $scope.lists = true;
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Some Error Occured ");
    });

Comment: json data are like:

Comment: DateStamp
:
"/Date(1509046061730)/"
ID
:
44
IsRead
:
true
Message
:
"my testing hello"
SenderID
:
1
SenderName
:
"Udal (Admin) "
SenderType
:
1
Subject
:
"my testing hello"