# How to convert timestamp to human date in javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below code i am trying to convert timestamp and Date Time format

```js
var d = new Date(637181249816089920);
console.log("dd",d)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript

Comment: [`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: sample code if i get from you guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to convert timestamp to human date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript)

Comment: if total number of count is 13 like 1382086394000 then it will work but my number is 18 count 637181249816089920 then it is not converting let me know

Comment: Read [MDN: `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). There is a limit in what timestamps are supported. Why would you even need dates that are hundreds of thousands of years from now?

Comment: yes i need date time year months