# Timestamp to date in datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, timestamp

I'm using Datatables and one of my column is a timestamp, how can I convert it to have a date into date format (YYYYmmJJ or JJmmYYYYY)?
[image]

I tried to add those lines :

```
columnDefs: [ {
  targets: 2,
  render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'YYYY/MM/DD', 'Do MMM YY', 'fr' )
} ]
```

but got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment is not a function

Maybe my timestamp is in the wrong format (ms).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to convert timestamp to human date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date for more options when formatting a `Date` object.

Comment: Did you include moment.js in page? That error is telling you there is no `renderer.moment`