# How to convert a Timestamp into MySQL DateTime in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime, unix

I have a timestamp format which is just like below which is an `int`.

```
1631514003973
```

I am passing this value to an API which is built with Node.JS. How can I convert this into `Mysql DateTime` format?

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150727/1379286) answer but it is about getting the current date and not converting a timestamp. I am coming from a Java background so this is bit confusing for me.

Comment: Send the timestamp to MySQL as-is and convert in a query. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca9b94a30156bcf7c5cf944931283976

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function to convert timestamp to human date in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485353/function-to-convert-timestamp-to-human-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `Date` object of JavaScript directly to MySQL. And MySQL will automatically generate the `DateTime` format from that `Date` object.

```js
const date = new Date(1631514003973);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that integer represents number in milliseconds since the [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). If that is the case try this code:

```
const numberOfMs = 1631514003973; 
const epochDate = new Date(1970,1,1);
const myDate = new Date(epochDate .getTime() + numberOfMs);
```

Answer (score 0):

we need to create a new function using JavaScript.

```html
<script>
        var timestamp = 1607110465663
        var date = new Date(timestamp);

       console.log("Date: "+date.getDate()+
          "/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+
          "/"+date.getFullYear()+
          " "+date.getHours()+
          ":"+date.getMinutes()+
          ":"+date.getSeconds());
    </script>
    
    Output:
    Date: 4/12/2020 19:34:25
```

If you want only date (MM/DD/YYYY), you should fallow this:

```
var timestamp=1370001284;
var todate=new Date(timestamp).getDate();
var tomonth=new Date(timestamp).getMonth()+1;
var toyear=new Date(timestamp).getFullYear();
var original_date=tomonth+'/'+todate+'/'+toyear;
console.log(original_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use either in nodejs layer. You need to convert the timestamp to date using below and use in the mysql query.

```js
const date = new Date(1631514003973);
console.log(date)
```

For the use direct in mysql you can use mysql date function and

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(DATE(1631514003973)), '%e %b %Y') AS 'date_formatted' FROM table
```